# #include or #import <objc/runtime.h>?

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, import, include

For an iPhone app, should I #include or #import , and why?

I've seen it done both ways, e.g., [#import](http://www.codecollector.net/view/2F26056B-EC5A-4FC3-8886-9C7C39DFF07F) & [#include](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2010/01/understanding-objective-c-runtime.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the header file has traditional [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), it really doesn't matter which you use, it's more of a stylistic choice.  There might be a *tiny* performance boost if you use `#import` instead of `#include`, but I doubt it will be noticeable, since most compilers these days are smart enough to recognize include guards and optimize accordingly.

If, on the other hand, the header file does **not** have include guards, then you should always use `#import`, since `#import` will ensure that the header will only get included once -- if you accidentally `#include` such a header twice, you will almost certainly get a deluge of compiler errors about redefinitions etc.

Since most Objective-C headers (especially those coming from the Objective-C runtime or the Cocoa headers) do not have include guards, you should use `#import` when including those.  When including standard C library headers or headers from a third-party library, it doesn't matter which you choose -- pick one style and be consistent.

Answer (score 6):

use #import.  the advantage is that it does not "re-include" files if they've already been included.

Answer (score 5):

Always use `#import` - it will make sure that the same header file is never `#include`'d twice.